# htaccess language detection and redirect: redirect loop issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm not really a pro in modifying .htacess files so I used http://www.htaccesstools.com/redirection-by-language/ generator to create redirect for different languages.

It should have two options: redirect to "ru" folder if browser language is russian and all other languages go to default page in english. However, it seems I just don't get it right and it also causes redirect loop.

Code looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (ru) [NC]
RewriteRule .* %sitename%/ru/index.html [R,L]
```

It would be also if redirect will be disabled if user changes language manually using selector. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure these rules are your very first rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ru [NC]
RewriteRule !^ru(/.*)?$ /ru/index.html [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^ru(/.*)?$ /index.html [R,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already in the `/ru/` folder, the browser's accept-language will still be the same, which means your condition will still be true, which means it'll redirect you back to the ru folder eventhough you're already there.

You'll need to make a check that you're not already in the `/ru/` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (ru) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!ru/) %sitename%/ru/index.html [R,L]
```

And to redirect out of the ru folder if the language is something else:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !(ru) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ru/ %sitename%/index.html [R,L]
```

Comment: Alas still the same redirect loop :(

I also tried to use such code:


    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ru [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$%sitename%/ru/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$%sitename% [L,R=301]


    RewriteRule ^$%sitename% [L,R=301]

It doesn't cause any loop issues, but it doesn't work as intended as well.