# htaccess language redirect loop chrome

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hey guys I am new to the .htaccess stuff and I am encountering a problem.
My goal is to have every Dutch and Belgium user redirected to bloggerlist.nl and the remaining should be redirected to bloggerlist.co.

I tried some [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924697/htaccess-language-detection-and-redirect-redirect-loop-issue) but it didn't work for me, so here's my htaccess for bloggerlist.nl:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bloggerlist.co [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!en/) http://www.bloggerlist.co [R,L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And the bloggerlist.co htacces is the same except for the three lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bloggerlist.nl [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (nl) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!nl/) http://www.bloggerlist.nl [R,L]
```

So this works in safari etc. but not in chrome. I think this is due to chrome having multiple supported languages in the browser ( English and Dutch) and the htaccess detects those languages and then it keeps redirecting them. With safari the browser language is on Dutch only, so this works as desired.

So I had the idea to don't redirect anymore if the HTTP_HOSTS is already from bloggerlist.nl or bloggerlist.co.

I didn't implement the Belgium language yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @anubhava could you take a look maybe

Comment: If it works in any browser (safari) then it means rules are probably working fine. In chrome open **Developer Tool** and reload your page. Then observe in Net tab if there is any wrong redirect happening.

Comment: @anubhava thank you for your response, I did what u said. And what I already thought it is redirecting to each other. Picture: http://imgur.com/3rpsVLV . And I think this is because of chrome having multiple languages and htaccess does see that and it will redirect to both: thus in a loop. Still searching for a solution, thanks in advance!